# Boolean difference makes messy mesh

Tags: boolean-modifier

[image]

I want to make a hole in my piece for a pear shaped diamond. I used the pear shaped diamond for the boolean but it messes up the mesh a little bit. What am i doing wrong?
Is there maybe another way to get this right?

Comment: The Boolean operation often creates bad topology, you need to correct manually or use another method than Boolean, maybe show an image of your reference object if you have one

Comment: You should rather cut a hole in the current topology, maybe share your object so that we can take a look?